# How to re-position the scroll bar in fancy box?

Tags: css, fancybox

How can i reposition the scroll bar in fancybox.I need to show it at the very right side of the browser like normal scroll bar.

[image]

There is a scroll bar which is of fancybox.I want to show it at the place where arrow is pointing.

Comment: Can you please provide some code or jsfiddle link for better understanding

Comment: check the edited question.It might help you understand better

Comment: what is the puspose of this? you may use width 100%

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    'width' : 100%,
    });

Comment: what's your fancybox content? if it is an iframe, then you definitely can't move the scroll bar out of the fancybox.